# Can not read received data from QNetworkAccessManager::finished slot when received data is large

Tags: c++, qt, networking, network-programming

I am using the QNetworkAccessManager class to do a GET request to a URL. I have connected the finished() signal to a slot I named httpReply() and the code for this slot can be seen below.

I have tried two different pages on the same server. The first is smaller (~1500 bytes) and the second one is about 45000 bytes.

The first page prints fine with qDebug() in the application output window. The second one does not print anything at all, not even an empty string like: ""

I thought maybe qDebug() did not like the size so I tried to write it to a file, but nothing gets written to the file.

I suspect maybe the readAll() function? I tried readLine(), but again nothing was printed.

And now I am stuck..

**EDIT1:**
I get the correct size when calling the bytesAvailable() function.

**EDIT2:**
I tried a different compiler using the same version of Qt (5.4.0) and it did still not work. I then tried a previous version of Qt, both 5.3.0 and 5.2.0 both with the same two compilers and it works as expected.

I guess there is a bug in 5.4.0 (or some functional change I can not see)?

**httpReply():**

```
void MyClass::httpReply(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << reply->bytesAvailable();
    qDebug() << "Reply: ";
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: Is `MyClass::httpReply()` called at all?

Comment: Yupp, for both pages. Also the size of the reply is correct according to bytesAvailable().

Comment: There might be a null character in the response.